# Django 4 by examples - Blog - send email issues

Tags: django

I was working on Django by Examples. Under Blog/share I am unable to send the email. Sharing all relevant blocks of code here. This is a copy paste of the code provided in the book, but I am still getting an error

This is the views.py file

```
def post_share(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,
                             id = post_id,
                             status = 'Post.Status.PUBLISHED')
    sent = False
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(
                post.get_absolute_url())
            subject = f"{cd['name']} recommends you to read " \
            f"{post.title}"
            message = f"Read {post.title} at {post_url}\n\n" \
            f"{cd['name']}\'s comments: {cd['comments']}"
            send_mail(subject, message, 'anupam.iitm@gmail.com', 
                      [cd['to']])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    
    return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post,
                                                    'form': form,
                                                    'sent': sent})
```

url patterns

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    # post views
    path('', views.post_list, name = 'post_list'),
    ## path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),  ## this is the same as above but using classes. However, some error and it is not working as expected
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/', 
         views.post_detail, 
         name = 'post_detail'),
    path('<int:post_id>/share/',
         views.post_share, name = 'post_share'),
]
```

share.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Share a post{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  {% if sent %}
    <h1>E-mail successfully sent</h1>
    <p>
      "{{ post.title }}" was successfully sent to {{ form.cleaned_data.to }}.
    </p>
  {% else %}
    <h1>Share "{{ post.title }}" by e-mail</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="Send e-mail">
    </form>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is resolved, status = 'Post.Status.PUBLISHED' should not be within quotes